# Can I re-download the Songs of Innocence download I once had without an Apple Music subscription?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I used to have the [U2, Songs of Innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songs_of_Innocence_(U2_album)) album on my phone, that was a free download from Apple in 2014. (This was [slightly controversial](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/u2-iphone-how-do-i-get-thing-album-off_n_5824416) at the time.)

I can't see it on my iPhone X, running 13.3 in Apple Music App under music or purchases. Nor can I see it in the iTunes app under downloads or purchases on my phone.

The [instructions on Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201272), from the [linked help page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6562078), indicate that having Apple Music enabled is a pre-requisite for downloading it. I don't have Apple Music enabled.

This came out prior to Apple Music. I don't understand why it would be associated with it.

In addition, I can see the Songs of Innocence Album on my phone using [iMazing](https://imazing.com/) under Music, looking as if it needs to be downloaded from the Cloud.

[image]

My question is: **Can I re-download the Songs of Innocence download I once had without an Apple Music subscription?**

Comment: Request a list of purchases on https://privacy.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it **without** an Apple Music subscription, provided you had an iPhone at the release time in 2014 and still have the same Apple account.

For this this was:

Music App -> Library -> Artists -> U2 -> Songs of Innocence -> Download.

[image]